# how to find area of right angle triangle given perimeter and three angles

Tags: trigonometry

So given a triangle with angles $90,30,60$ degrees and perimeter of $5(3 + \sqrt 3)$ find the area.

I thought about how it's half an equilateral triangle and generated the following equation:

$5x^2 +3x = 15 + 5\sqrt 3$ where $x$ is the length of the shortest side.

Where do I go from here??

Comment: A $30-60-90$ triangle has sides in the ratio of $1:\sqrt3:2$.

Comment: aah, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

A $30-60-90$ triangle has sides in the ratio of $1:\sqrt3:2$.  We can parameterize this by writing $$\text{perimeter}=t+\sqrt3t+2t=5(3+\sqrt3).$$

By inspection, we can see that $t=5$.  Noting that the area is going to be the half the product of the sides $t\times\sqrt3t$, we have $$\text{area}=\frac12\times5\times5\sqrt3=\boxed{\frac{25\sqrt3}2\ \text{sq. units}}.$$

Comment: got it thanks!!

Comment: Also how are you formatting the equations ie how are you typing out square roots on a keyboard?

Comment: @Krishna see [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thank you for that